# Store multiple objects with Symfony2 authentification

Tags: php, symfony

I have these tables in the database :

```
user:
- email
- lastname
- firstname
- password

userType1:
- fkUser
- specialCol1
- specialCol2

userType2:
- fkUser
- specialCol1
- specialCol2
```

I've made the Symfony2 authentification service working with `user` table but i want to store in the session (or in other place manage by the authentication) the associated object: `userType1` or `userType2`.

Futhermore, i want to redirect the user to its account depending on his type.

So my questions :

How to make treatement after submitting authentification form ? (to determine which type of user it is)

How to tell to Symfony to manage an other object (the user type) in the authentification context ?

Comment: You should be able to get the user object in a controller with `$this->getUser()` from there on you could simply get the related types with your getter for them i.e. `$this->getUser()->getTypes()`. It depends on your mapping files. In my opinion you don't really need to save those values in the session.

Comment: If i don't store it, i have to make a request to the database for each request while i could get it directly from session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the cookbook-entry [How to load Security Users from the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#authenticating-someone-with-a-custom-entity-provider). The sections "Authenticating Someone with a Custom Entity Provider" and "Managing Roles in the Database" might be helpful.

I had a similar problem with an authentication-procedure where a User and their Tenant-memberships were required. I built a custom provider which basically looks like the one from the cookbook. When serializing the User I only use certain field (id, username, email) and the rest of the data is fetched via the provider's `refreshUser()`, where again the User and their relationships are fetched via QueryBuilder. I had the problem, that when serializing the User in the session, the relationships were "lost" otherwise and I had to refetch the User all the time.

After that it's basically what @BenjaminPaap wrote. You retrieve the user [as described in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object) and get the user types, etc.

If you want to redirect the user to a certain target depending on their userType, you might want to look at "[How to create a custom UserProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)". [The Listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-listener) provides everything you need to redirect the user according to their type right after login.

Comment: ok for the first part, i will fetch data each time.. For the second part, i read about the listener but i don't see where i can redirect or do something else, and how to register it.

Comment: After you retrieve the AuthenticationToken (line 40 in the Listener-listing), additionally to setting the Token in the SecurityContext you create a (Redirect)Response-object and set it as the event's Response-object - similar as to how it is done in the catch-block. As to how to configure your bundle, I don't think I can explain this in a short comment. Just look at the Configuration-section and follow the path. There was a discussion about a simple AuthenticationProvider on the issue tracker, but I'm not sure how far it is progressed, I don't think it will make it into 2.2 though...

Comment: The cookbook-entry covers pretty much all you need for your custom Authentication procedure, except for the default AuthenticationManager referenced in the Listener (`@security.authentication.manager`). You could probably simplify things by also using a default Provider and Token. In that case just look at the configuration reference for `security.*`. Otherwise you have to work through the example from the cookbook. Best start with the Configuration and then follow through each component. It's quite complicated to get through, but helps getting a better grasp how things are done.

Comment: Just for reference, this is the issue where the simple authentication was discussed: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/6069